# AxVLCPlugin2 cant play video file

Tags: c#-4.0, vlc, libvlc

I am using 2 vlc libraries AxAXVLC and AXVLC.  So I can add vlc control in my c# winform application.  In this application I can play rtsp video stream by just add play list and call tha API play.  But I cannot play a video file.  The code to play video stream is given below.  It is working.  Please help me to play video file.

```cs
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear();
string Options3 = ":rtsp-caching=250"; //Cache in mS
int stream1 = axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("rtsp://10.1.114.51:8554/test", axVLCPlugin21, Options3);
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.playItem(stream1);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To play video files using AVLCPlugin2 below code can be used.
The only thing you need to do is convert URI to AbsoluteUri.

```cs
var uri = new Uri(@"c:\sample.mp4");
var convertedURI = uri.AbsoluteUri;
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(convertedURI);
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```